# Android studio AVD closing automatically after 5seconds of launch

Tags: android, windows, api, android-virtual-device, launch

i'm using Android studio 1.0.2 on windows 8.1

when i try to launch avd, avd launch and holds approx 5secs. then avd closes automatically.

i also tried to launch avd in different API LEVELS, But it doesn't works. the result is same..it closes after some seconds.

log shows:

"E:\Apps\Android Utilities\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_S_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none

FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:89:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1144 max1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/). The native Android emulator is horrible. I have seen corrupted images, and also the performance is awful. I have not seen these same problems with Genymotion. If you do not try Genymotion, then I recommend deleting and recreating this image, as it sounds like it is possibly corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "**-http-proxy none**" (without quotes) in Run configuration fixes this issue as shown in image attached.

[image]